# Getting a blank page with PHP&MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting a blank page with this code:

```
session_start();
include "config.php";
$af = $_GET['id'];
database_connect();
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE usr1 = '".$id."' AND usr2 = '".$af."'";
$result2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
if($row2['id']){
 echo "<script type='javascript'>alert('You are already friends with this person.');</script>";
 header('Location: profile.php?id="'.$af.'"');
}else{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO friends (usr1, usr2)  
            VALUES ('".$id."', '".$af."')") or die(mysql_error());
            echo "<script type='javascript'>alert('You two are friends now!');</script>";
        header('Location: profile.php?id="'.$af.'"');
};
};
```

This is the config.php (i changed the variables here though)

```
$h = "localhost";    
$u = "user";      
$p = "pass";   
$d = "datab";  

$sql = 'SELECT id FROM craffyposts limit '.($page*$eachPage).','.$eachPage;

$sql_count = 'SELECT id FROM craffyposts';


function database_connect(){
    global $h, $d, $u, $p;

    $link = @mysql_connect("$h","$u","$p"); 
    $sql_error = mysql_error();

    if (!$link) { 
        echo "Connection with the database couldn't be made.<br>";
        echo "$sql_error"; 
        exit;
    }

   if (!@mysql_select_db("$d")) {; 
        echo "The database couldn't be selected.";
        exit;
    }
   return $link;
}

if($_SESSION['usrid']){
    database_connect();
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM craffyusers WHERE id='" .$_SESSION['usrid']. "' ") or die (mysql_error());
    while ($obj = mysql_fetch_object($query)) {
   $id = htmlspecialchars($obj->id);
   $username = htmlspecialchars($obj->username);
   $email = htmlspecialchars($obj->email);
   $realname = htmlspecialchars($obj->name);
   $srvrid = htmlspecialchars($obj->serverid);
   $propic = htmlspecialchars($obj->profilepic);
    };
};
```

What's the issue here?

Comment: do you have results in $result2?

Comment: If you're getting a blank page, it quite possibly means that your php.ini error_reporting is set not to display errors. (The correct setting for a production environment.) Have you checked the Apache error logs?

Comment: @manji depends whether the row that is being searched after exists. thats where that if($row2['id']) is for

Comment: Cannot see anything that would obviously cause the symptoms you describe. Can you post the code for `database_connect()`? Also: you can't send headers after you have already sent output. You had probably better do the redirecting in JavaScript, given that you want a JavaScript error message to appear first. Also, please learn about SQL injection.

Comment: @Hammerite i am sure database_connect function is fine, i am using it all over the place atm, no problems with it. And thanks for that, i changed it to window.location in the javascript, but it doesn't fix the issue here. And yes I am aware of it, this is pure code to try it out and then i'll add the neccesary steps for SQL injection.

Comment: @gdscei, ok but if $row2 is false, while is not executed at all, right?

Comment: @manji that's an idea.. but how should i approach in a different way then?

Comment: I posted an answer, may be it will help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because there will 0 or 1 result, you can remove the `while` clause:

```
$row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);

if($row2 && $row2['id']){
 echo "<script type='javascript'>alert('You are already friends with this person.');</script>";
 header('Location: profile.php?id="'.$af.'"');
}else{
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO friends (usr1, usr2)  
            VALUES ('".$id."', '".$af."')") or die(mysql_error());
            echo "<script type='javascript'>alert('You two are friends now!');</script>";
        header('Location: profile.php?id="'.$af.'"');
};
```

Comment: Thanks, though it still displays as a blank page.

Comment: what do you expect it do display?

Comment: nothing, i expect it to give an alert box and redirect a user after something has been done, depending on the if($row2['id'])

Comment: I tested the "`alert`" part and I see that you're missing `text` in `type="javascript"`: you should have `<script type="text/javascript">`

Comment: alright, but now it gives me the alert that i am already friends though there are no rows in the table?

Comment: there was an error in my code (added a check on `$row2`) [if you're using it] but otherwise can you output what's in $row2 after running the query?

Comment: $row2 is `Array` and $row2['id'] is `1`

Comment: strange, are you sure when you execute this query `SELECT * FROM friends WHERE usr1 = '".$id."' AND usr2 = '".$af."'"` directly on the database you have no results?

Comment: yes. and there are no rows in the table actually, so it should do the else statment.

Answer (score 0):

Add this lines at the beginning of the script

```
        error_reporting(E_ALL);
        ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

The error will appear.

Comment: does not display anything, seems like something my host turned off, I'll ask them.

Comment: maybe you are missing the mysql library ...add some echo 'msg';die; and see if it dies before or after mysql_query

Comment: No, in my control panel php error messages were turned off. I'll have to wait a few minutes though before it's turned on.

Comment: It's giving an error that a variable isn't assigned, though this is clearly not the issue since the same error happens on other pages, but they don't have the issue. the variable is a variable in config.php where the code which uses that variable is only used in one certain page.

Comment: then include the config.php or set a default value for the variable

Comment: alright i included a default value, no error displays now but still a blank page. Also, as I said in the comments of the question, the config file is not the issue here since it works fine with other pages.

Comment: ok, do it the old fashion way: add an echo after each line and see where it stops.

Comment: I think it thinks that the row2['id'] exists, tho really it does not since there are no actual rows yet in the table. it does not go to the else statement but it does go after the first echo which contains the code for the first alert saying that they are already friends.

Comment: Someone else (check the comments in the other answer) kinda answered the question here, but you can see that i still have issues.